# Php8 attributes full gramar

Tags: php, attributes

We're trying to work on Php8 attributes grammar parser but we are not able to find full Php8 attributes grammar.

Does anyone know if there is any full language grammar for Php attributes?

(I checked also official documentation but there are only few information about attributes: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.php)

Thanks

Comment: I've only looked briefly at the syntax and additions to Reflection. Not sure I'm clear on what you are asking.  If I follow, then maybe look at VSCode bases highlighter code or PHP source even?

Comment: What we would need is a full grammar of attributes to be able to parse Doctrine attributes (we have a tool for Php ORM's imports/exports www.skipper18.com), so we would need to import and export all attributes to be able to parse it and visualize it.

Comment: Regarding VS code, it's a interesting idea. I will check it. Thanks

Comment: FWIW: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/attributes_v2 some talk specifically about Doctrine there. Go up from there and you can see a few RFC versions relating to attribute syntax as it changes under each PHP version. I'm thinking the PHP [ReflectionAttribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionattribute.php) class and source could be helpful. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, @ficuscr, I have also found mentioned attributes_v2, unfortunately, it's a only proposal for older and not used syntax ;-(. I already tried to search for all RFCs but I found only proposals/compares of several proposals but not the final version.

Comment: There is also this proposal https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shorter_attribute_syntax but it's also only proposal for several formats and not final one.

Comment: An attribute is a free-form word that follows rules for class-naming (although it doesn’t actually have to be backed by a class), followed by optional parentheses, with either positional or named arguments. Beyond that, what more from a “grammar” would you want? Or are you talking about Doctrine’s specific implementation, not attributes in general?

Comment: I believe there has to be some universal grammar for attributes at all. For example: Root=#[Attr1,Attr2,...],  Attr=Name|Name(params),  Params=param1,... , etc. But we already made our own grammar, so hopefully, we didn't miss anything.

Comment: The final version is [Shorter Attribute Syntax Change](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shorter_attribute_syntax_change).  Which replaced [Shorter Attribute Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shorter_attribute_syntax).  Which modified [Attributes v2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/attributes_v2).  The [implementing commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/8b37c1e993f17345312a76a239b77ae137d3f8e8).  Not an answer, but perhaps someone can find the answer in those resources.